# Error when reading in .adf raster file

Tags: attributes, raster, rgdal

When reading in a raster dataset I get the below error. Previously I have been able to read this same raster dataset successfully in R in this way, maintaining access to the attribute table and correct field names. I've tried updating the files with backups to eliminate the issue of corrupt files and I still get the below error. Besides corrupt files, what may be causing this error?

> dat2 <- raster("data/data_LEMMA/lemma_clip/w001001.adf") 
>   Error :     GDAL Error 3: Failed reading table field info for table
>   lemma_clip.VAT File may be corrupt?
>
> Warning message: In .rasterFromGDAL(x, band = band, objecttype, ...) :
>   Could not read RAT or Category names

Comment: If it is not the file, this could be a bug in gdal. Can you run `rgdal::GDALinfo(filename)` and command line `gdalinfo` on the file? Presumably they will both fail. Can you open the file with Arc?

Comment: Yes, I can open the file with Arc just fine. When I run the rgdal::GDALinfo("file path") I get a summary output with the error: 
    Warning message:
    In rgdal::GDALinfo("data/data_LEMMA/lemma_clip/w001001.adf") :
      statistics not supported by this driver (also how does one add the grey highlight?)

Comment: Can you try `GDALinfo("data/data_LEMMA/lemma_clip/w001001.adf", returnRAT=TRUE, returnCategoryNames=TRUE)`  (use back-ticks for highlighting). I assume that it will give the same error, suggesting that the VAT (=RAT) table is corrupted. Perhaps it is not (as Arc reads it), or perhaps it is (if Arc ignores it).

Comment: I get a similar error with the above call but I am able to open and view the attribute table fine in arc. `Error in GDALinfo("data/data_LEMMA/lemma_clip/w001001.adf", returnRAT = TRUE,  : 
  
 GDAL Error 3: Failed reading table field info for table lemma_clip.VAT File may be corrupt?
In addition: Warning message:
In GDALinfo("data/data_LEMMA/lemma_clip/w001001.adf", returnRAT = TRUE,  :
  statistics not supported by this driver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an ESRI GRID that works fine with Arc, but not with GDAL (when reading the Raster Attribute Table (RAT; or VAT in ESRI speak)). It would be useful if you could make it available for others to look at and look for a solution.

A work-around is to not read the RAT; perhaps that is acceptable in this case.

```
dat2 <- raster("data/data_LEMMA/lemma_clip/w001001.adf", RAT=FALSE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the RAT. I could read in the full LEMMA dataset (https://lemma.forestry.oregonstate.edu/data/structure-maps) and then select only desired attributes to summarize data by polygon but due to processing time and memory limitations I am trying to clip the dataset (In Arc) to the geography of interest before summarizing the RAT by polygon (in R). Are you suggesting I attach the clipped LEMMA data to my original post? Thank you for all your help with this.

Comment: I can now reproduce this problem after downloading the file following the link and using GDALinfo("gnn_sppsz_2014_08_28/mr200_2012", returnRAT=TRUE)`. The VAT.adf file is very large. I *can* run gdalinfo on the command line. It prints 5,553,269 lines! Most of them for the VAT.

Comment: What would your recommendation be for moving forward with this then?